# Issue with Hide / Show Jquery on fixed positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I've got a sticky footer at the bottom of the webpage / viewpoint as well as clickable link "toggle menu" that SHOULD hide / show the menu. Problem is that I can't get the menu to hide and I've picked up that the problem lies within the CSS of the element that is supposed to hide / show. It's the fixed position {position:fixed;} ... When I remove "fixed" out, then the hide and showing of the menu works 100% but obviously the menu is no longer at the bottom of the browser.

How can I get work this with the fixed positioning?

Javascript to show/hide goes like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").show();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});

</script>
```

HTML Goes like:

```
<div id="stick_footer_title"><a class="show_hide" href="#">Toggle Menu
 &#x25BC;</a></div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
<div id="stickyfooter">

<ul id="footer_menu"> 
    <li class="imgmenu"><a href="#"></a></li>

    <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
    </div>
```

FYI: The position:fix; css applies to the STICKYFOOTER div

Comment: Have you tried appending a `position: relative` container inside your `position: fixed` footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you hide the "stickyfooter" div, instead of the container?That way, the container will always be fixed (and shown), but when you hide the content, it will have nothing shown in it.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! :) I'm still not sure WHY this works as it seems like there's no difference except applying the hide/show javascript to another div that still has the fixed positioning. Anyway the main thing is that it works! Appreciate your help dude!

Comment: I don't know "why", but i encountered the same problem, and used this workaround, too :)

Comment: Simple answers are always the best

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving a duration parameter?

Like this:

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
```

Comment: I haven't got a duration parameter, though I was going to add one (exactly the one you mentioned above) after I have sorted my issue out. Are you saying I must try add one?

Comment: I added the parameter as mentioned above (needed to anyway and it's much better thanks) but I still need help on my issue ...

Answer (score 0):

Move position fixed from #stickyfooter to .slidingDiv if you can, or create a new element inside #stickyfooter that you'll hide/show.