# Jquery hide / show div but to keep toggle link from "hiding" too

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

I've just posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162387/issue-with-hide-show-jquery-on-fixed-positioned-div) on stackoverflow about a hide/show issue I was having but that's been resolved, though this is a follow up on that as I have come across another issue.

Ok, so I've got a sticky footer nav and there is a link just above the nav (also "sticky") that says "Toggle menu" ... when I click to hide the menu, the link that I've just clicked also hides. So basically there is no way to make the menu visible again cos the toggle button has also disappeared!

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#stickyfooter").show();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$("#stickyfooter").slideToggle("slow");
});


});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="stickyfooter">
<div id="stick_footer_title"><a class="show_hide" href="#">Toggle Menu &#x25BC;
</a></div>

<ul id="footer_menu"> 
<li class="imgmenu"><a href="#"></a></li>

<li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
<li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Now I know the `stick_footer_title` is within the div that gets hidden (hence why it disappears) but I'm not sure how to make it so that when I click "Toggle Menu" the link lowers with the menu that's about to disappear but STILL shows and can be clicked again to show raise / show the nav.

I've tried fiddeling with the Jquery but I'm not good with jquery. I'm pretty sure that I need to do something in the Jquery, like a .show(); parameter but I've just been guessing to try get this right.

Any solutions?

GENERAL CSS:

```
#sticky_footer_title { position:absolute; top: -35px; left: 20px; background-
color:#FF0000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color:#FFF; 
text-shadow:none;line-height: 34px; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px }


#stickyfooter {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
margin:0 auto;
width: 960px;
left:52%;
margin-left:-530px;
height: 40px;
background:#e9e9e9;
border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
z-index:1200;


/* CSS3 Stylings - Creates the double top border */
-moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #e9e9e9;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px -1px 0px #e9e9e9;
box-shadow:  0px -1px 0px #e9e9e9;

/* CSS3 Rounded Corners */
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;

/* CSS3 Stylings - Creates the gradient background */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #e9e9e9);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#e9e9e9), to(#FFF));
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the sticky footer toggle out the sticky footer div. The following code should work for you:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="stickyfooter">
    <div id="sticky_footer_title"><a class="show_hide" href="#">Toggle Menu &#x25BC;</a></div>
    <div id="stickyfooter">
        <ul id="footer_menu"> 
            <li class="imgmenu"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var $showhide = $(".show_hide");
var $stickyfooter = $("#stickyfooter");
var $stickyfootertitle = $("#sticky_footer_title ");

$stickyfooter.show();
$showhide.show();

$showhide.click(function(){
    var showMenu = $("#stickyfooter").css("display") == "block";

    $stickyfooter.slideToggle("slow");

    if(showMenu )
    {
        $stickyfootertitle.animate({
            bottom:'0px'
        }, "slow");
    }
    else
    {
       $stickyfootertitle.animate({
            bottom:'40px'
        }, "slow");
    }
});
```

**​CSS**:

```
#sticky_footer_title { 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom: 40px; 
    left: 50px; 
    background-color:#FF0000; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18px; 
    color:#FFF; 
    text-shadow:none;
    line-height: 34px; 
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 
}


.stickyfooter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}

#stickyfooter {
    height: 40px;
    background:#e9e9e9;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    z-index:1200;


    /* CSS3 Stylings - Creates the double top border */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #e9e9e9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px -1px 0px #e9e9e9;
    box-shadow:  0px -1px 0px #e9e9e9;

    /* CSS3 Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;

    /* CSS3 Stylings - Creates the gradient background */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #e9e9e9);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#e9e9e9), to(#FFF));
}

/* General typography stylings, paragraphs and H2 tags */

#stickyfooter h2 {
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#FF6600;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin:12px 0;
}
#stickyfooter p {

    color:#cccccc;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    line-height:18px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px 0;
}
#stickyfooter img {
    border:none;
}
#stickyfooter a {
    color:#FF6600;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#stickyfooter li ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 12px 0;
}

#stickyfooter .strong { /* Forcing a bold text */
    font-weight:bold;
}
#stickyfooter .italic { /* Forcing an italic text */
    font-style:italic;
}
.clear { /* Use this class between rows of content when you use columns */
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* Images containers */

#stickyfooter .imgshadow { /* Better style on dark background */
    background:#FFFFFE;
    padding:4px; /* Makes the light borders thanks to the background color */
    border:1px solid #333333;
    margin-top:5px;
    /* CSS3 shadow */
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000000;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000000;
}
#stickyfooter .img_left { /* Image sticks to the left */
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 15px 5px 0px;
}
#stickyfooter .img_right { /* Image sticks to the right */
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    margin:5px 0px 5px 15px;
}

/* Black background text box */

#stickyfooter .black_box {
    background-color:#111111;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
    margin-bottom:6px;

    /* CSS 3 Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* CSS 3 Inset Shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #000000;
}

/* Social Icons */

#stickyfooter #social {
    float:right; /* Positionning of the social icons container */
    width:auto;
    margin:5px 15px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#stickyfooter #social li {
    margin-right:12px; /* 12px is the space between each one of them */
    _margin-right:0px; /* IE6 only */
    float:left;
    width:24px;
    padding:0px;
    height:32px;
    list-style:none;
}
#stickyfooter #social li:hover {
    margin-top:-1px; /* Icons move 1px up on hover, you can remove this if you don't like */
}

/* Tooltips for social icons */

a.tooltip:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* The "span" defines the text appearing on mouse hover, these are basic stylings */
a.tooltip span {
    display:none;
    padding:5px;
    bottom:44px;
    position:relative;
    width:55px;
    text-align:center;
    /* CSS3 Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
a.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #333333;
    background:#181818;
    color:#dddddd;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:-20px;
}



/*  _______________________________________

    02 FOOTER - DROP DOWN MENU (DROP UP)
    _______________________________________  */



#footer_menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:auto;
}
#footer_menu li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font-size:11px;
    padding: 12px 10px 14px 10px;
    border-right:1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-left:1px solid #d9d9d9;
    background:#FFF;

    /* CSS3 Stylings - Creates the gradient background */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF, #e9e9e9);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FFF), to(#d9d9d9));
}

#footer_menu li:last-child { background:none; border:none; }

#footer_menu li:hover {
    background:#FFF;
    /* CSS3 Stylings - Creates the gradient background */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2f2f2, #FFF);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f2f2f2), to(#FFF));
}
#footer_menu li:hover:last-child { background:none; border:none; }

#footer_menu li a {
   display: block;
   color: #434343;
   text-decoration: none;
}
#footer_menu li a:hover {
   color: #000;
}
#footer_menu .imgmenu { /* Used for the home item, text is here hidden and replaced by an image */
    padding:5px 8px 0px 8px;
    border:none;
    background:none;
}
#footer_menu .imgmenu a { /* Used for the home item, text is here hidden and replaced by an image */
    background:url("img/home.png") top left no-repeat;
    width:36px;
    height:30px;
}
#footer_menu li.imgmenu:hover {
    background:none;
}
#footer_menu li.imgmenu a:hover {
    background:url("img/home2.png") top left no-repeat;
}

/* Drop Up */

/* You may have heard about drop down menus, the principle is here the same except that
   the content is going up instead of down */

#footer_menu li ul.dropup {
   display: none; 
   width: 15em; /* Width for Opera */
}
#footer_menu li:hover ul.dropup  {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 -16px;
    bottom:40px; /* Distance to the bottom of the browser */
    background-color:#222222;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    border-bottom:none;

    /* CSS3 Stylings - Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
}
#footer_menu li:hover li { /* Drop up default lists */
    float: none;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #161616;
    padding:8px 10px 8px 10px;
}
#footer_menu li:hover a {
    color: #aaaaaa;
}
#footer_menu li:hover a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#footer_menu li:hover p {
    margin:6px 0;
}

/* Right Panel */

#footer_menu .right { /* Use the right class to push the content to the right */
    float:right;
    right:10px;
}



/*  _______________________________________

    03 FOOTER - COLUMNS CONTENT
    _______________________________________  */



/* Following the principles of the 960 grid, we define here 3 containers
   which can contain from 1 to 3 columns */

#stickyfooter .dropdown_1column, 
#stickyfooter .dropdown_2columns, 
#stickyfooter .dropdown_3columns {
    margin:4px auto;
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    display:none;
    text-align:left;
}

/* Drop Downs Sizes */

#stickyfooter .dropdown_1column {width: 140px;}
#stickyfooter .dropdown_2columns {width: 280px;}
#stickyfooter .dropdown_3columns {width: 420px;}

/* Showing Drop Down on Mouse Hover - Left aligned */

#footer_menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#footer_menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#footer_menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 -16px;
    bottom:40px;
    background-color:#222222;
    border: 1px solid #111111;

    /* CSS3 Stylings - Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
}

/* Columns sizes, they have to be placed within a dropdown_columns DIV */

#stickyfooter .col_1,
#stickyfooter .col_2,
#stickyfooter .col_3 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#stickyfooter .col_1 {width:130px;}
#stickyfooter .col_2 {width:270px;}
#stickyfooter .col_3 {width:410px;}

/* Lists stylings */

#footer_menu li ul.simple { /* Reset stylings for other lists inside columns */
    margin-left:5px;
}
#footer_menu li ul.simple li {
    border:none;
    padding:0px;
    width:120px;
    line-height:24px;
    margin-left:5px;
}


.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/6/)

Comment: Hi, thanks - I am aware of the absolute position and although that does work, it still doesn't "sink down" with the collapsing menu if you know what I mean? How do other guys achieve this cos I've seen it many time before. I will try find a website as an example. In the meantime, I've updated my question and put in the necessary CSS in

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. Though as explained to dutchie432 above I need this to look exact. I've tried to put this on JSfiddle though it doesn't work, but this is how it should be but without the TOGGLE MENU link dissapearing http://www.hdvirtualtour.co.za/collapse/index.html ... surely by adding some javascript parameter I can .show(); the stick_footer_title ?

Comment: Isn't a Peekmount needed in the javascript to still show some of the div (which would be the TOGGLE MENU bit)?

Comment: Heres an example of what I need. The only difference In the video tho, the tabs the expand are on the sides. http://codecanyon.net/item/css3-fixed-slide-out-tabs/full_screen_preview/1470793

Comment: What do you mean by Peekmount? Also what do you mean you put in in a jsfiddle and it doesnt work? I supplied a jsfiddle and it working perfectly.

Comment: A Peekmount... It's apparently an amount of the div that stays visible, but honestly this could have been someone elses personal terminology. For some reason when try put together the contents of hdvirtualtour.co.za/collapse/index.html in JSFiddle, it doesn't come out the same! My luck!

Comment: Check out [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ukEuP/12/) Is it more of what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks so much for trying hard! Unfortunately it's not. Have you checked my link out? I'll try to put it together on JSFiddle again...

Comment: As mentioned above - it isn't showing like it should on JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/ ... if you take a look at my personal link above you will see what I've got to so far.

Comment: If you click this link http://latesthackdemo.blogspot.com/ on the right hand side are twitter and facebook links. They are hover activated but that's exactly what I want, except, click activated and they stay there untill you click the button again to hide the content.

Comment: You are my HERO!!! That's what I'm talking about!! SHOW ME THE MONEY!!!!!!!!!! Haha, wow, I've been trying to get that effect ALL day... searching searching Testing Testing! Thanks so much bro! You've put more effort than you should have. I seriously need to learn more javascript and your answer solution will help just that!!!

Comment: Your welcome! Glad to be of help! Solving problems like this helps to test my skills and to improve my knowledge of javascript too. :)

Comment: I can' thank you enough! Just a question, when I copy and paste those codes into dreamweaver, It doesn't work like yours... what haven't I done?

Comment: Do you have an example site up? It depends on what is not working.

Comment: I've uploaded exactly what you've given me on a different HTML page (index2.html and footer2.css) http://www.hdvirtualtour.co.za/collapse/index2.html ... check the source code... is it not Doctype? Or...

Comment: You need to add the jquery in a $(document).ready(function() {}); I did not have it in the jsfiddle because of how jsfiddle works.

Comment: Hey, thanks... I've added it now but it doesn't seem to be working still: Could you check to see if I've done it correct? hdvirtualtour.co.za/collapse/index2.html - refresh and check view source.

Comment: You seem to have an extra `}` before your closing `)`

Comment: Hmmm... I removed that curly bracket and it still shows the same?

Comment: You are now missing the closing `});` for the `$(document).ready(function() {}); ` You may want to format your javascript better so it is easier to see the closing brackets.

Comment: That's what it was!!!!!! Thank you AGAIN!! We have been working on this for 3 hours! Big ups to you!

Comment: One more question and then I won't bug you anymore! IF I wanted to make it so that when you load the page, the menu is already in the closed state and when you click the "toggle menu", it slides the menu up... then from them the user can toggle open or closed like it already does ... :D

Comment: I actually tried doing that earlier and unfortunately it didn't worked :( ... If it's a mission, honestly you don't have to work this out.

Comment: Remove that line and add class="show_hide" to the sticky footer. I assumed it already had it since it was being told to show. I should have checked the first time.

Comment: I'm so sorry, add class="show_hide" to the div ID stickyfooter? Or a particular javascript code? I really struggle with Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Take the toggle link out of the hidden div? You'll also want to position the elements absolutely using their `bottom`'s so they appear to slide out from the footer item.

### JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ukEuP/8/

### HTML

```
<div id="stickyfooter">
    <ul id="footer_menu"> 
        <li class="imgmenu"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="stick_footer_title">
    <a class="show_hide" href="#">Toggle Menu &#x25BC;</a>
</div>
```

​

### JS

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $('#stickyfooter').slideToggle();
});​
```

### CSS

```
#stick_footer_title a{color:#fff}
#stick_footer_title{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    background:#000;
    color:#000;
    width:100%;
}
#stickyfooter{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
}
.show_hide{margin:5px;}
```

Comment: I want the toggle link to be almost attached to the menu that can show / hide. If I take it out of the toggled div then the link won't be "attached" anymore if you understand what I mean?

Comment: You might need a second link to appear. Something like this, but cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/ukEuP/4/

Comment: Remember this is a FOOTER Nav like: http://codecanyon.net/theme_previews/128701-pure-css3-sticky-footer?index=1

Comment: If that's the case, you should not have the clickable object inside of the menu. the clickable object should remain stationary while the menu expands/collapses.

Comment: Thanks for the JS fiddle links... though what happens if it's a footer nav like the link I posted above?

Comment: Then you need to position the menu item with `bottom:0` to make it appear to be scrolling UP

Comment: I agree with you that it shouldn't be inside the div but I've seen websites that have a menu at the bottom of the browser where you can collapse / expand. When the menu collapses there is still a Plus sign or a little button to press that expands the meny again

Comment: Look at this link. This is what you want - and its with the link outside of the div. http://jsfiddle.net/ukEuP/8/ - the elements are anchored by their bottoms so slideUp and slideDown appear to be reversed.

Comment: Thanks SO much for the effort. If I could give you votes I would. Appreciate it! BUT, I need the TOGGLE MENU button above the menu :-| sorry for being a pain!