# JQuery fix menu div show and hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have some problems for show the div container of menu, when I go over the link which active the div for show, the div show ok, but at the same time hide and no stay, the idea it´s show the div and stay and when I go out the div this must hide.

The basic problem is that:

1. When I put my mouse over the link for display the menu, the menu shows perfectly in the first moment,
2. But if I put the mouse over the div - show until - of menu show, this menu hide all time and doesn't stay.

With this script I am trying to show `div` and when the mouse go out of this `div`, hide it.

My Script is this:

```
function menu(id,width,color)
{

$(".men"+id).mouseover(function() {



$(".m"+id).css("width",""+width);
$(".m"+id).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
$(".m"+id).css("background-color",""+color);



});

$(".m"+id).mouseout(function() {


$(this).hide(500);


});

}
```

CSS Style :

```
#content_menu
{
margin-top:7px;
position:absolute;
min-height:50px;
height:auto;
border:1px solid;
text-align:left;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
z-index:2;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity:0.8;
-khtml-opacity: 0.8;
opacity: 0.8;
}

#content_menu_into
{
position:relative;
width:98%;
min-height:28px;
height:auto;
line-height:28px;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:14px;
color:#000000;
padding-left:2%;
text-align:left;
}
```

And for call script :

```
   <a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:menu('1','200','#000000');" class="men1">
   Home Web Menu
   </a>
        
        
    <div id="content_menu" class="m1" style="display:none;">
    <div id="content_menu_into">
    Home
    News
    Articles
    Users
    Vote
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Look at this answer.It may give some information to you.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162387/issue-with-hide-show-jquery-on-fixed-positioned-div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162387/issue-with-hide-show-jquery-on-fixed-positioned-div)

Comment: I'd suggest you to use [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/), and recreate a working example of the code.

Answer (score 0):

delete min-height style,and try to use javascript to achieve its effect.

```
#content_menu
{
//min-height:50px;
}
```

and replace the javascript with the following code

```
function menu(id,width,color)
{
$(".m"+id).css("width",width);
$(".m"+id).css("background-color",color);
$(".men"+id).mouseover(function() {

$(".m"+id).slideDown(500);
});
$(".m"+id).mouseout(function() {

$(this).slideUp(500);

});
}
```

---

```
$(".m"+id).css("width",width);
$(".m"+id).css("background-color",color);
```

I think the code above can be removed or be called first in menu function.Because you just change the value of the element's style but don't need to change it back.So I removed them.

I don't know if it's your expected effect.

Answer (score 0):

made some changes in your code.Hope this helps you:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></Script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#content_menu").hide();
$(".men1").hover(
function(){$("#content_menu").show()},
function(){$("#content_menu").hide()}
)


})

</script>
<style>

#content_menu
{
    margin-top:7px;
    min-height:50px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    z-index:2;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity:0.8;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 20%;
}

#content_menu_into
{
    position:relative;
    min-height:28px;
    height:auto;
    line-height:28px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000000;
    padding-left:2%;
    text-align:left;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="men1">
   Home Web Menu

  <div id="content_menu" class="m1" >
    <div id="content_menu_into">
    Home
    News
    Articles
    Users
    Vote    </div>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```